# Grails get domain properties

Tags: grails

I'm trying to accelerate the performance of my app and wonder if there is a difference between accessing domain property value with `instance.name` and `instance.getName()`

If it is, which one is the best in terms of performance ?

Example

```
class   User {
    String name
}
User user = User.get(100);

//is it better this way
user.name

//or this way
user.getName()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely you will find a lot easier ways for improving performance of your code. Here are some ideas where to start if you like to improve performance.

A) Number of queries. Try to avoid the the N+1 problem. For example if one user hasMany [events: Event], code like user.events.each { access event.anyPropertyExceptId } will dispatch new queries for each event.

B) Efficiency of queries. Grails per default creates indexes for all gorm associations / other nested domains. However anything you use to search, filter etc. you need to do "manually" for example.

```
static mapping = {
    anyDomainProperty index: 'customIndexName'
}
```

C) Only query for the data you are interested in, replace for example:

```
User.all.each { user ->
    println user.events.size()
}
```

with

```
Event.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property('user')
        countDistinct('id')
        groupProperty('user')
    }
}
```

D) If you really need to speed up your groovy code and your problem is rather a single request than general cpu usage, take a look at http://gpars.codehaus.org and http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/guide/async.html and try to parallize work.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter for the usage you've provided, because `user.name` uses `user.getName()` behind scenes. So it's the same. If you want to access property directly you have to use @ like this `user.@name`. See more [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Javafield%28.@%29)

But I don't think this is the way you can speed up your app.

Comment: Ok thank you, about accessing the property directly with @ what is it for ?

Comment: If you need to access field directly when you for example override getter.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt any performance issues in your application are related to how you are accessing your properties of your domain classes. In fact, if you profile/measure your application I'm sure you will see that is the case.